# Microsoft Dynamics AX File(.ald) Convert PDF or Print

Tags: windows-7, extract, print-to-pdf, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax

I need to extract this file as pdf. Can you help me ?

Thank you

file:http://yanityayincilik.com/akillitahta/prf/PRF-LYS-Matematik.zip

1.ald file virustotal https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/c83378327d5b6f57e92da98677752d2d582e8196c42ff0980fbda72184392b4c/detection

screenshots :imgur.com/a/tCbVQk4

file content imgur.com/a/Mt7eVwz

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the site https://topdf.com to see if it can convert your file.  I doubt many people here are going to try opening a random zip file for fear of infection.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/tr/url/7526d1f02c4a3b72887978f14e093177b88806c416f5c04fddb892db1440d4bf/analysis/1534863150/

Thanks for answer but 
pdf not translated

Comment: Oh. So you want it converted AND translated?

Comment: yes i tried. 
Wrong file format. Allowed: 123, AZW, AZW3, AZW4, BMP, CBR, CBZ, CGM, CHM, CSV, DJV, DJVU, DOC, DOCX, DXF, EMF, EPUB, FB2, GIF, HTM, HTML, HTMLZ, JPEG, JPG, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODG, ODM, ODP, ODS, ODT, OXPS, PBM, PCD, PCT, PCX, PDB, PGM, PML, PNG, PPM, PPS, PPT, PPTX, PRC, PSD, PUB, RAS, RB, RTF, SDA, SDC, SDD, SDP, SDW, SLK, SVG, TCR, TEXT, TEXTILE, TGA, TIF, TIFF, TPZ, TXT, TXTZ, UOF, UOP, UOS, WB2, WK1, WKS, WMF, WPD, WPS, XBM, XLS, XLSB, XLSX, XML, XPM, XPS.

Comment: I want to print this file with the printer.

Comment: What format is the doc inside of the zip file?

Comment: please wait sir  
I add a screenshot

Comment: @TomBrackman That VirusTotal link doesn't tell us anything. VirusTotal checked the site but didn't download or scan the file: `The response exceeds the maximum file size allowed by the application. VirusTotal will only download files under 32MB in size.`

Comment: @TomBrackman Okay. What I'm asking is just to know the extension of the file contained in the zip archive.  You won't be able to convert the zip itself to a PDF but if you extract the file in it, you should be able to convert THAT file to a PDF.

Comment: screenshots :https://imgur.com/a/tCbVQk4

Sir, virustotal 
I tested it on the link

Comment: @TomBrackman That looks to be program not a document.  You've got EXE and DLL files in there.

Comment: file content https://imgur.com/a/Mt7eVwz

Comment: I'm very confused now. Which of those files are you trying to convert to PDF?

Comment: PRF-LYS-Matematik>Ayarlar>Book>PRF-LYS-Matematik>Pageİmages>1.ALD

1.ALD file size 39MB


I want to convert this file

Comment: This is test book. 
I want to print and solve the questions

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that. That's a proprietary format that appears to be something to do with Microsoft Dynamics AX